# Google Sheets: How can I FILTER a range based on a value in the previous row?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm working with a golf data set and I'm looking for a way to filter holes based on the result of a previous hole. In the end, I want this range to be able to get the average score of the golfer following a bogey or worse.

I've made a few attempts with `FILTER()`, `OFFSET()`, and even `INDIRECT()`, but I can't figure out how to properly use values from a different row as the condition for my filter.

- `=FILTER(A2:D10, OFFSET(D2:D10, -1, 0) >= 1, ROW(D2:D10) <> 2)` (errors with "FILTER has mismatched range sizes.")
- `=INDIRECT("D"&FILTER(ROW(A2:D10)+1, D2:D10 >= 1, ROW(D2:D10) <> 2))` (only returns the first value)

**Sample Data:**

```
      A      B      C      D
    -----------------------------
 1 |  Hole   Par    Score  ScoreDiff
 2 |  1      4      5      1
 3 |  2      4      4      0
 4 |  3      4      3      -1
 5 |  4      5      6      1
 6 |  5      3      3      0
 7 |  6      5      6      1
 8 |  7      3      4      1
 9 |  8      4      5      1
10 |  9      4      4      0
```

**Desired outcome:** only the holes *directly following* a bogey or worse (where `ScoreDiff >= 1`)

```
      A      B      C      D
    -----------------------------
 1 |  2      4      4      0
 2 |  5      3      3      0
 3 |  7      3      4      1
 4 |  8      4      5      1
 5 |  9      4      4      0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simpler option:

```
=FILTER(A3:D11,D2:D10>=1)
```

[image]

Comment: I was really overthinking this, didn't consider that the "mismatched" range arguments in filter would behave this way. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=FILTER(A2:D10, {""; D2:D9} >= 1, ROW(D2:D10) <> 2)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm marking the simpler answer as the solution, but this has some helpful elements as well. Specifically, getting the ranges to match with `{""; ... }` is great.